# Suming combinations in binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

Hello. I was looking for the proof of binomial theorem by mathematical induction and I reached this step . I just don't understand why the terms underlined red are canceled out .

Comment: check the definition of a binomial coefficient $n \choose k$ when $k < 0$ or $n < k$ and you will see

Comment: Can I enter the minus inside the binomial coefficient ?

Comment: Okay thank you now I understood the reason they canceled out , but still need to know if I could enter the minus inside it

Comment: what do you mean by "enter the minus inside it"?

Comment: $$\binom{a}{b} = \begin{cases} \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!} & \textrm{if } b\geq0,\;a\geq b\\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you . I mean by entering the minus that the terms in the picture have a minus before them . Can I put the minus outside , inside the binomial coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We define for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{r}{k}=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{r(r-1)\cdots (r-k+1)}{k(k-1)\cdots 3\cdot2\cdot1}&\qquad k\geq 0\tag{1}\\
> 0&\qquad k<0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

We obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\binom{n-1}{n}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2\cdot 1\cdot \color{blue}{0}}{n(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=0
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\binom{n-1}{-1}=0
\end{align*}

since the lower entry $-1$ is negative.

> *Hint:* You might find  chapter $5$ *Binomial Coefficients* (definition above is (5.1)) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by  R.L.Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful.

Comment: If r and k were both negative , could I pull a minus outside the binomial coefficient , so that they become positive and the coefficient then would give us an integer ?

Comment: @ZaKh: No, there is no useful generalization for negative integer values $k$.

Comment: Just a note that in Mathematica $\binom{-1}{-1}$ evaluates to 1 and there are cases where this is natural.

Comment: @Maesumi: Thanks for the hint.